# Asynchronous sockets in ring transfer

Tags: sockets, asynchronous

I trying to write program, that combines several machines in ring. And after that I send token around this ring. I have a problem: when marker has passed around the ring once and I want to send it second time, machine doesn't want to accept it marker. Sometimes VS rises exception, sort of "... host forcibly closed the connection". Before this problem did not arise at work with asynchronous sockets...
I guess, that problem in listening socket, that work out 1 time and closed. But how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance for your help.
Function, that initializes machines:

```
private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!connected)
        {
            //some operation
        }
        else 
        {
            //some operation
        }
        try
        {
            sendS = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            recieveS = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            portFrom = int.Parse(port1TextBox.Text);
            portTo = int.Parse(port2TextBox.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            port1TextBox.Text = "Incorrect!";
        }

        IPAddress ipAddressFrom = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.122");
        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAddressFrom, portFrom); //IPAddress.Any

        sendS.Bind(ipEnd);
        sendS.Listen(1);
        sendS.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(accept), null);
    }
    public void accept(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        Socket sock = sendS.EndAccept(asyn);
        // Let the worker Socket do the further processing for the just connected client
        begin(sock);

        // Since the main Socket is now free, it can go back and wait for
        // other clients who are attempting to connect
        sendS.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(accept), null);
    }

    public class SocketPacket
    {
        public Socket m_currentSocket;
        public byte[] dataBuffer;

        // Constructor that takes one argument. 
        public SocketPacket(int size)
        {
            dataBuffer = new byte[size];
        }
    }

    public void begin(Socket s)
    {
        AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(serialPort1_DataReceived);
        SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket(15);
        theSocPkt.m_currentSocket = s;
        s.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, pfnWorkerCallBack, theSocPkt);
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
        int iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
        byte[] dataBytes = socketData.dataBuffer.ToArray();
        for (int i = dataBytes.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (dataBytes[i] != 0)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref dataBytes, i+1);
                break;
            }
        }

        Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
        String text = enc.GetString(dataBytes);
        analyze(text);            
    }
```

Function, that connects 2 machines:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (connected)
        {
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipTo.Text), System.Convert.ToInt32(portTo));
            recieveS.Connect(ip);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Solved. I forgot about string

```
begin(socketData.m_currentSocket);
```

at the end *serialPort1_DataReceived* function...